# QUERY: Using Karate DSL with javascript based UI automation framework

Tags: karate

I want to know, if we can use karate with JS based UI automation framework. And if yes, what are the requisite to follow. Do we require maven in that case?

We have well matured UI automation Selenium based framework. We want to know, if we can integrate Karate DSL without using maven.

Comment: fyi: Karate won't yet do Selenium Grid if you need to support multiple browser testing.

Comment: FYI the above comment is badly out of date: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#webdriversession

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might if you use the CLI (command line interface) provided by the stand-alone JAR / executable. Please read the documentation here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar

Which means if you can call an OS command from node / JS - you can use Karate. But there are no guarantees - and you can assume the answer to your question is *NO*.

That said - we plan to have our own competitor to Selenium - but it will take a little more time: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core

Comment: Thanks Peter, correct me if I am wrong - even with CLI we have to use maven right?

Comment: @p2018 no, you don't

Comment: Is there any github repo for examples showing usage of standalone jar. It will help me to kick start.

Comment: @p2018 maybe for you the answer is a strong **NO** :)